# model and instance methods: session aware (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So, using and learning with sqlalchemy.

I have an instance, I need to get a value. If that value exists, return it.
If not calculate and return it.

Invariably someone will say 'you're doing it wrong' and input on improvement is appreciated in general.
However I am looking into how I can do this without explicitly having to manage the session, because what I'm working on is starting to grow, and constantly managing the session for when I want to update an instance is problematic. It makes me think that I *am* in fact doing it wrong.

So how do I fix the method below to not have manage the session explicitly?

```
def method(self, session):
        if self.i_needed_this is None:
            self.i_needed_this = calculate(calcutron)
            session.add(self)
            session.commit()
            return self.i_needed_this                        
        else:
            return self.i_needed_this
```

Maybe this question should be titled 'making instances session aware so I'm not always explicitly managing it', and if it's a dumb question, at least show me why with examples and point me to where others have  asked better.

Edit: apparently, importing the session I'm using works, and it is available, so maybe its a non issue or a future one for when I am more skilled with sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your question is so common, that the answer to it is in the [Session Frequently Asked Questions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#session-frequently-asked-questions) of SA documentation:

- How can I get the Session for a certain object?
  Use the [object_session()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.object_session) classmethod available on Session:
  `session = Session.object_session(someobject)`

*However, it assumes the object is persistent and is either new (but added to a session already) or bound to a session. Your sample code contains logic to add the object to the session, so my assumption might not be true in this case.*

Comment: I found that as well and re read it, I was really just looking to find a better way of integrating a session to my models and this helps.

Comment: For completeness: `from sqlalchemy.orm import Session`

Comment: @blueblank I agree with you, I am not partial to it either, I feel it breaks the harmony of the way I like to code.

Answer (score 18):

See [How can I get the Session for a certain object?](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#how-can-i-get-the-session-for-a-certain-object):

- You can use SA Runtime Inspection API:

  ```
  from sqlalchemy import inspect
  # ...
  # within instance method
  session = inspect(self).session
  ```
- or `object_session()` method:

  ```
  from sqlalchemy.orm.session import Session
  # ...
  # within instance method
  session = Session.object_session(self)
  ```

Comment: Can anyone explain the difference between these two?

Comment: The link at the start of th answer goes directly to the documentation for SqlAlchemy.

Comment: you don't need to call `Session.object_session`, you could just import `object_session` itself, its a non-class method in the same module